# How to change the language of browser native datePicker?

Tags: html, datepicker

Hello I was playing around with HTML5 datePicker and I was wondering how I could change the default language of the widget. How to change the lang from english to german? Any idea?

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Birthday:
  <input type="date" name="bday">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Thanks

Comment: AFAIK you can't. This is controlled by the browser's locale, which can only be set by the user. I,e, users whose Chrome (or iOS or whatever), is set to German will have a German datepicker.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any way to change input type="date" format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format)

Answer (score 1):

the most common way to force to change the language is the next :

```html
<form lang="es">
        <input type="text" pattern="\d{1,15}" required />
        <input type="submit" />
    </form>
```

if you want more information about declare language, can you learn more in the next links :

http://nimbupani.com/declaring-languages-in-html-5.html

I hope my answer is helpful.

Comment: Neither this nor the meta tag worked for me (on Chrome). The datepicker remained localized in the same language used by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This works on safari but not in Chrome or Firefox:

```html
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Geburtstag:
  <input type="date" name="bday" placeholder="tt/mm/jj">
  <input type="submit" value="einreichen">
</form>
```

However you can use [polyfills](https://remysharp.com/2010/10/08/what-is-a-polyfill) to make it work on all browsers.
Look at [this example](https://www.npmjs.com/package/date-input-polyfill) of a module to understand it better.

Comment: the placeholder and the actual calendar are still in my browsers' language. FF v.75.0

Comment: Yes, FF changed it since then. (this post is from 2 years ago) Use the polyfill then.

Answer (score 0):

type `date` for html is browser native control, at least for chrome this stands true. So it will be localised according to the language of the browser. However frameworks like bootstrap has better locale support or even you can set locale settings in jquery manually with some scripting at server side.